In TailwindCSS how to preserve aspect ratio on a div that has a flex container overlay?
In TailwindCSS trying to figure out how to force a div to have a 16:9 ratio at all times with a flex container of text overlayed. Currently the implementation I have crops the image with overflow-hidden. My CMS only provides 16:9 ratio images.
Code
<section aria-labelledby="test-area" class="mx-auto max-w-7xl my-16 w-full h-auto">
  <div class="relative overflow-hidden">
    <div class="absolute inset-0 aspect-video">
      <Image
        height={1080}
        width={1920}
        alt=""
        src="https://tailwindui.com/plus/img/ecommerce-images/home-page-03-feature-section-full-width.jpg"
        class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="relative bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50">
      <div class="relative flex justify-between gap-8 items-center shrink-0">
        <div class="flex flex-col max-w-4xl gap-8 p-16">
          <h2
            id="test-area"
            class="text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight text-white sm:text-4xl"
          >
            Bacon ipsum dolor amet leberkas brisket
          </h2>
          <p class="mb-0 text-white">
            Bacon ipsum dolor amet leberkas brisket drumstick doner kevin meatloaf. T-bone pork
            loin rump cow chicken shank. Turkey tri-tip brisket salami pork loin, turducken
            meatball kevin beef ribs drumstick jowl tenderloin bacon cow rump. Ball tip swine
            shankle chuck, ground round pork chop tri-tip chislic alcatra ham. Sausage fatback
            beef ribs ground round.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="">
            Shop Focus
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid gap-8 p-16">
          <div class="h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-red-400">1</div>
          <div class="h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-red-400">2</div>
          <div class="h-[100px] w-[100px] bg-red-400">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

Research
Didn't see a similar question:

Fill div with cropped image, preserve aspect ratio
Preserve aspect ratio using div
div scale to preserve aspect ratio
How to maintain aspect ratio of a portrait div on a wide screen with Tailwind css?
How can we use TailwindCSS to proportionally scale an image to always fit within the viewport?
Maintaining image aspect-ratio while absolutely positioning elements on top of image (tailwind aspect ratio plugin)
Contain contents of fixed aspect box in tailwind

In TailwindCSS how can I ensure a div always has an aspect ratio of 16:9 while I overlay a flexed div?

have you checked this: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/aspect-ratio

@Yilmaz yes if you reference the code I’ve tried to use aspect-video
